# Clear redux state when page transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I made a blog and store the single page state to redux state (singlePost). When I go to a specific post page, the singlePost is set to the post value. But When I go back to my homepage and click the next post, the next post page shows the previous value and immediately turn to the new value.

I try to dispatch the reset function if user presses the browser's go back button, but it seems not work. Could someone guide me how I improve this? Thank you!

**singlePostReducer.js**

```
export const singlePostReducer = createSlice({
  name: "singlePost",
  initialState: {
    isLoadingPost: false,
    singlePost: "",
    newPostResponse: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    setIsLoadingPost: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoadingPost = action.payload.isLoading;
    },
    setSinglePost: (state, action) => {
      state.singlePost = action.payload;
    },
    setNewPostResponse: (state, action) => {
      state.newPostResponse = action.payload;
    },
    resetSinglePost: (state) => {
      state.singlePost = "";
    },
  },
});
```

**SinglePost.js**

```
 export default function PostPage() {
      const { id } = useParams();
      const singlePost = useSelector((store) => store.singlePost.singlePost);
      const { body, title, createdAt } = singlePost;
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const history = useHistory();

      //Does 
      if (history.goBack() || window.onpopstate) {
          dispatch(reset());
        }

      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getSinglePost(id));
        
      }, [id, dispatch]);
    
      return (
        <PostPageContainer>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <h4>{new Date(createdAt).toLocaleString()}</h4>
          <PostContent>{body}</PostContent>
        </PostPageContainer>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

```
//Does
if (history.goBack() || window.onpopstate) {
  dispatch(reset());
}
```

The issue is that as written, `history.goBack()` will always be immediately invoked. I'm not sure what the return value is, but that isn't really relevant for you. `window.onpopstate` needs to have a callback assigned to it in order to work, but this also isn't want you want and assigning one would overwrite the global value and isn't recommended to do at all.

## Solution

You can dispatch your rest action from an effect clean up function when the component unmounts.

```
export default function PostPage() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const singlePost = useSelector((store) => store.singlePost.singlePost);
  const { body, title, createdAt } = singlePost;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getSinglePost(id));
  }, [id, dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => dispatch(reset()); // <-- reset when unmounting
  }, []);

  return (
    <PostPageContainer>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <h4>{new Date(createdAt).toLocaleString()}</h4>
      <PostContent>{body}</PostContent>
    </PostPageContainer>
  );
}
```